# Enhancements for text classification using word vectors

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, gensim, word2vec

I am using word vectors for text classification solution. I am using word vectors mainly to address the case of synonyms which are not there in the training set but will be present in the actual use-cases. By simply using word vectors, I am not getting a good enough accuracy in prediction. Can anyone please suggest some enhancements I can do over word vectors in order to improve accuracy?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  We can deal with a specific request, but not with a nebulous description.  Show your design and usage; show the accuracy you get, what you expect, and perhaps why you think that accuracy is possible with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

- Debug your bad prediction cases. Will good quality of embedding of synonyms (of those in the training dataset) help at all?
- Use a different embedding that is trained with larger vocabulary, with similar content as your application, etc.
- Get more training data (labeled dataset). This should help a lot. Text classification usually have a very large space of features.
- Allow "trainable" of your embedding layer when training your text classifier. Don't be confused with the word2vec training, which is to get a pre-learned embedding for your embedding layer and it could use a large amount of unlabeled data. Here you are using a relatively smaller dataset containing only labeled data. Allow the embedding layer to be "trainable" means that gradient could be back-propagated from the output layer to the embedding layer to fine-tune the embedding vectors.